# Handling null objects in nested observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have a viewmodel with several arrays of observables (budgets, companies, costcenters).
The Budgets has a CostcenterID and a computed observable that returns the costcenter for that budget from the costcenterlist based on the costcenterid.The costCenter has a companyID and a computed observable that returns the company for that costcenter from the company list based on the commpanyId.

In my view, i'n binding to the budgets and , I have

```
<td>
    <select data-bind="options:$root.Costcenter,optionsCaption:'cost center', optionsText:'Title', optionsValue:'Id', value:CostCenterId "></select>                         
</td>
<td>
    <span data-bind="text:CostCenter().Company().Title"></span>
</td>
```

It works fine if the budget has a costcenter, but when the costcenter is not present for a given budget i get a binding error

> 0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse
>   bindings.
>
> Message: TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method;
>
> Bindings value: text:CostCenter().Company().Title

(My computed observable for costCenter returns an empty Object {} if it doesn't find the costcenter based on the costcenterID).

Whats the best way to handle this without littering up my bindings with a bunch of if statements that check to see if an object is empty?

Answer (score 6):

An easy solution is to use the `with` binding to wrap your `Title` span and have `CostCenter` just return null when it is empty.

```
<td data-bind="with: CostCenter">
    <span data-bind="text: Company().Title"></span>
</td>
```

When `CostCenter` is null, it won't render the inner content and will not try to bind against properties/observables that don't exist.

Alternatively, you could create a computed observable that represents the `Title` specifically, like: `<span data-bind="text: CostCenterCompanyTitle"></span>`.  So, the computed in this case would handle checking to see if the CostCenter is defined.  If you have many properties to bind against though, this can complicate and clutter your view model.  Using the `with` binding is an easier choice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to wrap up any functionality related with the costCenter with a div (or the same td) for example that will check if this object is undefined or not:
like

```
costCenterAccessible = ko.computed(
function()
{
   return self.CostCenter() != undefined;
}, this
);


<td data-bind="visible: costCenterAccessible>
    <span data-bind="text:CostCenter().Company().Title"></span>
</td>
```

BUT if not all of the fields can be accessible you need to think twice it the using of the table for this task is the good solution.

Answer (score 0):

`<td>
    <div  data-bind="if: CostCenter()">
        <span data-bind="text:CostCenter().Company().Title"></span>
    </div>
</td>`

This Checks CostCenter before trying to print the Title.